# How to include IrdaClient.dll in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, network-programming

I want to use `IrdaClient` class to detect IRDA devices.

I have added following name spaces.

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
```

But still there is no such class available.

Am I missing anything??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the IR port on the back of my netbook to change the channel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901109/how-to-use-the-ir-port-on-the-back-of-my-netbook-to-change-the-channel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IRDA is only available on:

> ### Platforms
>
> Windows CE, Windows Mobile for Smartphone, Windows Mobile for Pocket PC
>
> <sup>[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.irdaclient(v=vs.90).aspx)</sup>